# Give a user permission to insert and remove computer from windows domain

Tags: active-directory

I want to give a specific domain user in my domain the permission to add/remove computers in the domain.

How do I do that? and more important, does anyone know what is the permission name that I need to give the user?

Thanks!

Comment: "Account Operators" can do this but be cautious, that role is still powerful with domain controllers. It is best to create your own security group of users and delegate them to be able to add/edit/remove computers. This way they can only do what you want them to do. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/76a8caba-01fd-40bc-8c8a-bd1110517ab5/account-operator-rights

Comment: I may be missing something here, but have you tried right click the domain > Delegate > click on "create computer accounts"?